# How can I create a small IDLE-like Python Shell in Tkinter?

Tags: python, shell, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to make a thing controlled by a Python Shell GUI.

The only thing is, I don't know how to make that whole input/output thing. I just want to be able to type an input, execute the python command and give the output of the python command. I know that IDLE is made in Tkinter, so it uses the widgets?

It's literally just a "type input, show output" thing.

I've tried searching it up but it seems like most of the results are to do with the command line, which isn't what I'm looking for. The only other question that was exactly like mine wasn't what I had in mind, either. I also tried loking up the source code for IDLE but couldn't find what I was looking for.

I've found some answers that work for Linux but I'm on Windows 10...

I need the "shell" to be in Tkinter because on one side of the screen will be something else which is connected to the command outputs.

Does anyone know the widgets used to make a very simple Python shell?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977525/how-to-use-idlelib-pyshell-to-embed-an-interpreter-in-a-tkinter-program might be of interest.

Comment: That question looks like a follow-up of another which is deleted, it kinda didn't make sense to me without the context from the deleted question...well, at least I know now it's possible - and that I'm not the only one trying to do something...again

Comment: Idle is written in python, using tkinter... read the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/idlelib).

Answer (score 10):

### Simple Python Shell / Terminal / Command-Prompt

---

- *********************    It's **literally** just a "`type input`, `show output`" thing. ************************

---

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from subprocess import *


class PythonShell:

    def __init__(self):
        self.master = Tk()

        self.mem_cache = open("idle.txt", "w+")
        self.body = None
        self.entry = None
        self.button = None
        self.entry_content = None

    @staticmethod
    def welcome_note():
        """
        To show welcome note on tkinter window
        :return:
        """
        Label(text="Welcome To My Python Program [Version 1.0]", font='Arial 12', background="#272626",
              foreground="white").pack()

        Label(text=">> Insert Python Commands <<", font='Arial 12', background="#272626",
              foreground="white").pack()

    def get_text(self):
        """
        This method will perform following operations;
        1- Get text from body
        2- Implies python compilation (treat text as command)
        3- Set Output in Output-Entry

        :return: get and set text in body of text box
        """
        content = self.body.get(1.0, "end-1c")
        out_put = self.run_commands(content)
        self.entry_content.set(out_put)

    def store_commands(self, command=None):

        try:
            self.mem_cache.write(command + ';')
            self.mem_cache.close()

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def get_stored_commands(self):
        try:
            with open("idle.txt", "r") as self.mem_cache:
                self.mem_cache.seek(0)
                val = self.mem_cache.read()
                self.mem_cache.close()
                return val

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    @staticmethod
    def check_if_file_empty():
        size = os.stat("idle.txt").st_size

        if size != 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def run_commands(self, command):
        """

        This method would return output of every command place in text box
        :param command: python command from text box
        :return: output of command
        """

        print("Running command: {}".format(command))
        value = None
        new_line_char = command.find('\n')
        semi_colons_char = command.find(';')
        double_quote = command.find('"')

        try:
            if new_line_char != -1:

                if semi_colons_char != -1 & double_quote == -1:

                    new_cmd = command.replace("\n", "")
                    cmd_value = '"' + new_cmd + '"'
                    self.store_commands(command)

                    value = check_output("python -c " + cmd_value, shell=True).decode()
                elif semi_colons_char == -1 & double_quote == -1:

                    new_cmd = command.replace("\n", ";")
                    cmd_value = '"' + new_cmd + '"'
                    self.store_commands(command)
                    value = check_output("python -c " + cmd_value, shell=True).decode()

                elif double_quote != -1:

                    cmd_1 = command.replace('"', "'")
                    new_cmd = cmd_1.replace('\n', ';')

                    cmd_value = '"' + new_cmd + '"'
                    self.store_commands(command)

                    value = check_output("python -c " + cmd_value, shell=True).decode()

                elif self.body.compare("end-1c", "==", "1.0"):
                    self.entry_content.set("the widget is empty")

            elif self.body.compare("end-1c", "==", "1.0"):
                value = "The widget is empty. Please Enter Something."

            else:
                variable_analyzer = command.find('=')
                file_size = PythonShell.check_if_file_empty()

                if file_size:
                    new_cmd = command.replace('"', "'")
                    cmd_value = '"' + new_cmd + '"'
                    stored_value = self.get_stored_commands()
                    cmd = stored_value + cmd_value
                    cmd.replace('"', '')

                    value = check_output("python -c " + cmd, shell=True).decode()
                elif variable_analyzer != -1:
                    new_cmd = command.replace('"', "'")
                    cmd_value = '"' + new_cmd + '"'
                    self.store_commands(cmd_value)

                    value = 'Waiting for input...'
                    pass
                else:
                    new_cmd = command.replace('"', "'")
                    cmd_value = '"' + new_cmd + '"'
                    value = check_output("python -c " + cmd_value, shell=True).decode()

        except Exception as ex:
            print('>>>', ex)
            self.entry_content.set('Invalid Command. Try again!!!')

        print('>>', value)
        # To Clear Text body After Button Click
        # self.body.delete('1.0', END)

        return value

    def start_terminal(self):
        """
        Initiate tkinter session to place and run commands
        :return:
        """
        self.master.propagate(0)
        self.master.geometry('750x350')
        self.master.title('Python IDLE')
        self.master.configure(background='#272626')

        terminal.welcome_note()

        self.body = Text(self.master, height='10', width='75', font='Consolas 12', background="#272626",
                         foreground="white",
                         insertbackground='white')
        # self.body.propagate(0)
        self.body.pack(expand=True)

        Label(text=">> Command Output <<", font='Arial 12', background="#272626",
              foreground="white").pack()

        self.entry_content = StringVar()
        self.entry = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.entry_content, width=50, font='Consolas 16',
                           background="white",
                           foreground="black")
        self.entry.pack()
        # self.entry.propagate(0)

        self.button = Button(self.master, text="Run Command", command=self.get_text, background="white",
                             foreground="black",
                             font='Helvetica 12').pack()

        self.master.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    terminal = PythonShell()
    terminal.start_terminal()
```

---

The above given python script has following hierarchy as given;

```
    |import ...      
    |class PythonShell:
        |def __init__(self):...

        @staticmethod
        |def welcome_note():...
        |def get_text(self):...
        |def store_commands(self, commmand):...
        |def get_stored_commands(self):...

        @staticmethod
        |def check_if_file_empty():
        |def run_commands(self, command):...
        |def start_terminal(self):...

    |if __name__ == '__main__':...
```

---

### Workflow:

The basic workflow for the above code is given as follows;

- `def welcome_note():...` Includes the Label that will display outside the text body.
- `def get_text(self):...` Performs two operations; ** Get text from text body ** & ** Set Output in the Entry Box **.
- `def store_commands(self, command):...` Use to store variable into file.
- `def get_stored_commands(self):`... Get variable stored in file.
- `def check_if_file_empty():`... Check Size of file.
- `def run_commands(self, command):...` This method act as **python compiler** that take commands, do processing and yield output for the given command. To run commands, i would recommend to use `subprocess-module` because it provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; To run *window-commands* using python includes various builtin libraries such as;

  **1.** **os** ([in detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system)), **2.** **subprocess** ([in detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)) etc.

  To checkout which is better to use, visit reference: [subprocess- module is preferable than os-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python).
- `def start_terminal(self):...` This method simply involves the functionality to initiate `tkinter` session window and show basic layout for input and output window.

  > You can further modify and optimize this code according to your requirement.

---

### Workaroud:

This simple `tkinter GUI based python shell` perform simple functionality as windows-command-prompt. To run python commands `directly` in command-prompt without moving into python terminal, we do simple as;

```
python -c "print('Hey Eleeza!!!')"
```

Its result would be simple as;

```
Hey Eleeza!!!
```

Similarly, to run more than one lines directly at a time as given;

```
python -c "import platform;sys_info=platform.uname();print(sys_info)"
```

Its output would be as;

```
My System Info: uname_result(system='Windows', node='DESKTOP-J75UTG5', release='10', version='10.0.18362', machine='AMD64', processor='Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel')
```

---

So to use this `tkinter python shell`;

- Either you can place command as;

  ```
  import platform
  value=platform.uname()
  print('Value:', value)
  ```
- or like this way;

  ```
  import platform;value=platform.uname();
  print('Value:', value)
  ```
- or simply inline command as

  ```
  import platform;value=platform.uname();print('Value:', value)
  ```

---

You will get the same result.

Comment: This input/output is perfect, thank you so much! Just one thing though, if I assign a variable, run the command and then clear and try to print the variable, it doesn't do that, so how would I get the command to run in the real-life python (if it's not doing that)?

Comment: @Eleeza , first of all your question has not  involved such type of requirement. As it is very basic `input`, `output`  shell. It acts like basic `python kernel`. *It only operate on which is placed in the text-body*. I haven't set any **buffer or memory-cache** to hold variable history. Let me check first for this requirement in this IDLE!

Comment: The thing I was going to make was a game where the whole world is programmed into the main code, and the terminal is used to explore it and interact with it. I thought it would just be a case of executing the code before showing the output but I'll have to check that.

Comment: Code is now optimize for only one variable buffer. You can modify according to you need. If it helps let me know. Thanks

Comment: Explained in detail: I'm making a sort of "world" in the main game program, where the people, the places etc, they are all objects in Python. The player has to navigate through the world through the GUI terminal, usung the python commands, it's a game about learning Python through exploring. The code is actually modified in real life (but it resets afterwards).

Comment: I thought it would be a case of just using the `exec()` command with the input, but that didn't work...

Comment: @Eleeza , Here is **best github repository** that can give you the complete track on which you are ; Visit reference : 

https://github.com/codecombat/codecombat .

Here are some other references you must have to look at these as well;

https://github.com/replit/play, https://github.com/jatinmandav/Gaming-in-Python, 

https://github.com/PacktPublishing/-Learn-Python-Programming-with-Games, 

https://github.com/kidscancode?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=&type=&language=python, 

https://github.com/pyland/pyland, 

Here is another reference as well 

https://github.com/CharlesPikachu/Games

Answer (score 5):

I had implemented python shell using `code.InteractiveConsole` to execute the commands for a project. Below is a simplified version, though still quite long because I had written bindings for special keys (like Return, Tab ...) to behave like in the python console. It is possible to add more features such as autocompletion with jedi and syntax highighting with pygments.

The main idea is that I use the `push()` method of the `code.InteractiveConsole` to execute the commands. This method returns `True` if it is a partial command, e.g. `def test(x):`, and I use this feedback to insert a `...` prompt, otherwise, the output is displayed and a new `>>>` prompt is displayed. I capture the output using `contextlib.redirect_stdout`.

Also there is a lot of code involving marks and comparing indexes because I prevent the user from inserting text inside previously executed commands. The idea is that I created a mark 'input' which tells me where the start of the active prompt is and with `self.compare('insert', '<', 'input')` I can know when the user is trying to insert text above the active prompt.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import re
from code import InteractiveConsole
from contextlib import redirect_stderr, redirect_stdout
from io import StringIO


class History(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        try:
            return list.__getitem__(self, index)
        except IndexError:
            return


class TextConsole(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        kw.setdefault('width', 50)
        kw.setdefault('wrap', 'word')
        kw.setdefault('prompt1', '>>> ')
        kw.setdefault('prompt2', '... ')
        banner = kw.pop('banner', 'Python %s\n' % sys.version)
        self._prompt1 = kw.pop('prompt1')
        self._prompt2 = kw.pop('prompt2')
        tk.Text.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        # --- history
        self.history = History()
        self._hist_item = 0
        self._hist_match = ''

        # --- initialization
        self._console = InteractiveConsole() # python console to execute commands
        self.insert('end', banner, 'banner')
        self.prompt()
        self.mark_set('input', 'insert')
        self.mark_gravity('input', 'left')

        # --- bindings
        self.bind('<Control-Return>', self.on_ctrl_return)
        self.bind('<Shift-Return>', self.on_shift_return)
        self.bind('<KeyPress>', self.on_key_press)
        self.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.on_key_release)
        self.bind('<Tab>', self.on_tab)
        self.bind('<Down>', self.on_down)
        self.bind('<Up>', self.on_up)
        self.bind('<Return>', self.on_return)
        self.bind('<BackSpace>', self.on_backspace)
        self.bind('<Control-c>', self.on_ctrl_c)
        self.bind('<<Paste>>', self.on_paste)

    def on_ctrl_c(self, event):
        """Copy selected code, removing prompts first"""
        sel = self.tag_ranges('sel')
        if sel:
            txt = self.get('sel.first', 'sel.last').splitlines()
            lines = []
            for i, line in enumerate(txt):
                if line.startswith(self._prompt1):
                    lines.append(line[len(self._prompt1):])
                elif line.startswith(self._prompt2):
                    lines.append(line[len(self._prompt2):])
                else:
                    lines.append(line)
            self.clipboard_clear()
            self.clipboard_append('\n'.join(lines))
        return 'break'

    def on_paste(self, event):
        """Paste commands"""
        if self.compare('insert', '<', 'input'):
            return "break"
        sel = self.tag_ranges('sel')
        if sel:
            self.delete('sel.first', 'sel.last')
        txt = self.clipboard_get()
        self.insert("insert", txt)
        self.insert_cmd(self.get("input", "end"))
        return 'break'

    def prompt(self, result=False):
        """Insert a prompt"""
        if result:
            self.insert('end', self._prompt2, 'prompt')
        else:
            self.insert('end', self._prompt1, 'prompt')
        self.mark_set('input', 'end-1c')

    def on_key_press(self, event):
        """Prevent text insertion in command history"""
        if self.compare('insert', '<', 'input') and event.keysym not in ['Left', 'Right']:
            self._hist_item = len(self.history)
            self.mark_set('insert', 'input lineend')
            if not event.char.isalnum():
                return 'break'

    def on_key_release(self, event):
        """Reset history scrolling"""
        if self.compare('insert', '<', 'input') and event.keysym not in ['Left', 'Right']:
            self._hist_item = len(self.history)
            return 'break'

    def on_up(self, event):
        """Handle up arrow key press"""
        if self.compare('insert', '<', 'input'):
            self.mark_set('insert', 'end')
            return 'break'
        elif self.index('input linestart') == self.index('insert linestart'):
            # navigate history
            line = self.get('input', 'insert')
            self._hist_match = line
            hist_item = self._hist_item
            self._hist_item -= 1
            item = self.history[self._hist_item]
            while self._hist_item >= 0 and not item.startswith(line):
                self._hist_item -= 1
                item = self.history[self._hist_item]
            if self._hist_item >= 0:
                index = self.index('insert')
                self.insert_cmd(item)
                self.mark_set('insert', index)
            else:
                self._hist_item = hist_item
            return 'break'

    def on_down(self, event):
        """Handle down arrow key press"""
        if self.compare('insert', '<', 'input'):
            self.mark_set('insert', 'end')
            return 'break'
        elif self.compare('insert lineend', '==', 'end-1c'):
            # navigate history
            line = self._hist_match
            self._hist_item += 1
            item = self.history[self._hist_item]
            while item is not None and not item.startswith(line):
                self._hist_item += 1
                item = self.history[self._hist_item]
            if item is not None:
                self.insert_cmd(item)
                self.mark_set('insert', 'input+%ic' % len(self._hist_match))
            else:
                self._hist_item = len(self.history)
                self.delete('input', 'end')
                self.insert('insert', line)
            return 'break'

    def on_tab(self, event):
        """Handle tab key press"""
        if self.compare('insert', '<', 'input'):
            self.mark_set('insert', 'input lineend')
            return "break"
        # indent code
        sel = self.tag_ranges('sel')
        if sel:
            start = str(self.index('sel.first'))
            end = str(self.index('sel.last'))
            start_line = int(start.split('.')[0])
            end_line = int(end.split('.')[0]) + 1
            for line in range(start_line, end_line):
                self.insert('%i.0' % line, '    ')
        else:
            txt = self.get('insert-1c')
            if not txt.isalnum() and txt != '.':
                self.insert('insert', '    ')
        return "break"

    def on_shift_return(self, event):
        """Handle Shift+Return key press"""
        if self.compare('insert', '<', 'input'):
            self.mark_set('insert', 'input lineend')
            return 'break'
        else: # execute commands
            self.mark_set('insert', 'end')
            self.insert('insert', '\n')
            self.insert('insert', self._prompt2, 'prompt')
            self.eval_current(True)

    def on_return(self, event=None):
        """Handle Return key press"""
        if self.compare('insert', '<', 'input'):
            self.mark_set('insert', 'input lineend')
            return 'break'
        else:
            self.eval_current(True)
            self.see('end')
        return 'break'

    def on_ctrl_return(self, event=None):
        """Handle Ctrl+Return key press"""
        self.insert('insert', '\n' + self._prompt2, 'prompt')
        return 'break'

    def on_backspace(self, event):
        """Handle delete key press"""
        if self.compare('insert', '<=', 'input'):
            self.mark_set('insert', 'input lineend')
            return 'break'
        sel = self.tag_ranges('sel')
        if sel:
            self.delete('sel.first', 'sel.last')
        else:
            linestart = self.get('insert linestart', 'insert')
            if re.search(r'    $', linestart):
                self.delete('insert-4c', 'insert')
            else:
                self.delete('insert-1c')
        return 'break'

    def insert_cmd(self, cmd):
        """Insert lines of code, adding prompts"""
        input_index = self.index('input')
        self.delete('input', 'end')
        lines = cmd.splitlines()
        if lines:
            indent = len(re.search(r'^( )*', lines[0]).group())
            self.insert('insert', lines[0][indent:])
            for line in lines[1:]:
                line = line[indent:]
                self.insert('insert', '\n')
                self.prompt(True)
                self.insert('insert', line)
                self.mark_set('input', input_index)
        self.see('end')

    def eval_current(self, auto_indent=False):
        """Evaluate code"""
        index = self.index('input')
        lines = self.get('input', 'insert lineend').splitlines() # commands to execute
        self.mark_set('insert', 'insert lineend')
        if lines:  # there is code to execute
            # remove prompts
            lines = [lines[0].rstrip()] + [line[len(self._prompt2):].rstrip() for line in lines[1:]]
            for i, l in enumerate(lines):
                if l.endswith('?'):
                    lines[i] = 'help(%s)' % l[:-1]
            cmds = '\n'.join(lines)
            self.insert('insert', '\n')
            out = StringIO()  # command output
            err = StringIO()  # command error traceback
            with redirect_stderr(err):     # redirect error traceback to err
                with redirect_stdout(out): # redirect command output
                    # execute commands in interactive console
                    res = self._console.push(cmds)
                    # if res is True, this is a partial command, e.g. 'def test():' and we need to wait for the rest of the code
            errors = err.getvalue()
            if errors:  # there were errors during the execution
                self.insert('end', errors)  # display the traceback
                self.mark_set('input', 'end')
                self.see('end')
                self.prompt() # insert new prompt
            else:
                output = out.getvalue()  # get output
                if output:
                    self.insert('end', output, 'output')
                self.mark_set('input', 'end')
                self.see('end')
                if not res and self.compare('insert linestart', '>', 'insert'):
                    self.insert('insert', '\n')
                self.prompt(res)
                if auto_indent and lines:
                    # insert indentation similar to previous lines
                    indent = re.search(r'^( )*', lines[-1]).group()
                    line = lines[-1].strip()
                    if line and line[-1] == ':':
                        indent = indent + '    '
                    self.insert('insert', indent)
                self.see('end')
                if res:
                    self.mark_set('input', index)
                    self._console.resetbuffer()  # clear buffer since the whole command will be retrieved from the text widget
                elif lines:
                    self.history.append(lines)  # add commands to history
                    self._hist_item = len(self.history)
            out.close()
            err.close()
        else:
            self.insert('insert', '\n')
            self.prompt()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    console = TextConsole(root)
    console.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: History isn't working for me as written, I think this line: `self.history.append(lines)  # add commands to history` should be `self.history.extend(lines)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple shell mainly using `exec()` to execute the python statements and `subprocess.Popen()` to execute external command:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys, io
import subprocess as subp
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

class Shell(tk.Text):
  def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
    tk.Text.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)
    self.bind('<Key>', self.on_key) # setup handler to process pressed keys
    self.cmd = None        # hold the last command issued
    self.show_prompt()

  # to append given text at the end of Text box
  def insert_text(self, txt='', end='\n'):
    self.insert(tk.END, txt+end)
    self.see(tk.END) # make sure it is visible

  def show_prompt(self):
    self.insert_text('>> ', end='')
    self.mark_set(tk.INSERT, tk.END) # make sure the input cursor is at the end
    self.cursor = self.index(tk.INSERT) # save the input position

  # handler to process keyboard input
  def on_key(self, event):
    #print(event)
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
      if self.cmd:
        # show the last command
        self.delete(self.cursor, tk.END)
        self.insert(self.cursor, self.cmd)
      return "break" # disable the default handling of up key
    if event.keysym == 'Down':
      return "break" # disable the default handling of down key
    if event.keysym in ('Left', 'BackSpace'):
      current = self.index(tk.INSERT) # get the current position of the input cursor
      if self.compare(current, '==', self.cursor):
        # if input cursor is at the beginning of input (after the prompt), do nothing
        return "break"
    if event.keysym == 'Return':
      # extract the command input
      cmd = self.get(self.cursor, tk.END).strip()
      self.insert_text() # advance to next line
      if cmd.startswith('`'):
        # it is an external command
        self.system(cmd)
      else:
        # it is python statement
        self.execute(cmd)
      self.show_prompt()
      return "break" # disable the default handling of Enter key
    if event.keysym == 'Escape':
      self.master.destroy() # quit the shell

  # function to handle python statement input
  def execute(self, cmd):
    self.cmd = cmd  # save the command
    # use redirect_stdout() to capture the output of exec() to a string
    f = io.StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(f):
      try:
        exec(self.cmd, globals())
      except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    # then append the output of exec() in the Text box
    self.insert_text(f.getvalue(), end='')

  # function to handle external command input
  def system(self, cmd):
    self.cmd = cmd  # save the command
    try:
      # extract the actual command
      cmd = cmd[cmd.index('`')+1:cmd.rindex('`')]
      proc = subp.Popen(cmd, stdout=subp.PIPE, stderr=subp.PIPE, text=True)
      stdout, stderr = proc.communicate(5) # get the command output
      # append the command output to Text box
      self.insert_text(stdout)
    except Exception as e:
      self.insert_text(str(e))

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Simple Python Shell')

shell = Shell(root, width=100, height=50, font=('Consolas', 10))
shell.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
shell.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

Just input normal python statement:

```
>> x = 1
>> print(x)
1
```

Or input a shell command:

```
>> `cmd /c date /t`
2019-12-09
```

You can also use `Up` key to recall the last command.

Please note that if you execute a system command requiring user input, the shell will be freeze for 5 seconds (timeout period used in `communicate()`).

You can modify `on_key()` function to suit your need.

*Please also be reminded that using `exec()` is not a good practice.*

Comment: Could you possibly explain the code through, please? I'm a bit of a beginner at all of this...and I don't know if I'm understanding correctly