# How to make a terminal like something using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, cmd, terminal

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

text = tkinter.Text(root)
text.pack()
while 1:
    x = input(">>>")
    if x == 'exit':
        break
    try:
        y = eval(x)
        if y: print(y)
    except:
        try:
            exec(x)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error:", e)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The while loop will block the tkinter `mainloop()` from executing.  Also there is no tkinter related code in the while loop.

Comment: This question ["how-can-i-create-a-small-idle-like-python-shell-in-tkinter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59164314/how-can-i-create-a-small-idle-like-python-shell-in-tkinter) may help.